# Python Peewee build queries dynamicly

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I have some model like this:

```py
class User(Model):
   username = CharField()
   email = CharField()
   disabled = BooleanField()
   admin = BooleandField()
   ...
```

and i want to write queries something like this:

```py
def apply_filter(query, filter):
   match filter:
      case "disabled":
          return query.where(User.disabled == True)
      case "admin":
          return query.where(User.admin == True)
      case "protonmail":
          return query.where(User.email % "%protonmail.com")
...

def get_users(filters):
    results = []
    try:
        query = User.select()
        for filter in filters:
            query = apply_filter(query, filter);
        for e in query:
            results.append(e)
```

where additional filters are applied dynamicly

how could I achive this or something simmilar

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared should work, as you're progressively adding additional filters to the query. Does it not work for some reason?

More generally, though, you can accumulate expressions in a list and then reduce them and pass them to `.where()`:

```
def apply_filter(filter):
   match filter:
      case "disabled":
          return (User.disabled == True)
      case "admin":
          return (User.admin == True)
      case "protonmail":
          return (User.email % "%protonmail.com")
...

from functools import reduce
import operator

def get_users(filters):
    results = []
    query = User.select()
    exprs = [apply_filter(f) for f in filters]
 
    # AND expressions together:
    query = query.where(reduce(operator.and_, exprs))

    # OR expressions together:
    query = query.where(reduce(operator.or_, exprs))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me, I had a typo lol